# MySQL online DB access in swift

Tags: mysql, ios, iphone, database, swift

what i've to do for getting, posting and checking data from a DB (MySQL) using swift?
Can I only create the php pages and contact them or there's a way to manage them? If yes, how?

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry for my english)

Yes you need a php script

In your swift file:

```
var bodyData = "name=value" //To get them in php: $_POST['name']


    let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "URL TO YOUR PHP FILE")
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    {
            (response, data, error) in
            var output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) // new output variable
            var array = self.JSONParseArray(output)
    }
```

in php:

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status;
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // Like in the bodyData var

//Doing sql things

$result = array(
    "result" => "VARIABLE TO SEND BACK"
);


sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

And if you wan't to get the result in an array use this function:

```
func JSONParseArray(jsonString: String) -> Array<String> {
    var e: NSError?
    var data: NSData!=jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
        data,
        options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0),
        error: &e) as Array<String>
    if e == 0 {
        return Array<String>()
    } else {
        return jsonObj
    }
}
```

Comment: How the third code works? i get an error at this point 
  var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &e) as Array<String>

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You need to give the output to this function and it return it back but in a array

Comment: Look at the first code i have updated it check the output and array variable

Comment: I have the same pietro's error...  I made same check and I see that -----NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments , error: &e)----- return a nil value... What's the mistake?

Comment: Did you try: var array = self.JSONParseArray(output)

(With the self.)

Comment: What beta version of xCode do you have?

Comment: NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror)------ This return nil... I use the last xCode beta (xCode 6 beta 6)

Comment: Is self.JSONParseArray(output) in the NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest block ?

Comment: Yeah, now I re-copied your code and I see that this code "NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &e) as Array<String>" return a nil... I'm desperate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60039/discussion-between-giorgio-nocera-and-clement-bisaillon).